# If any item of list starts with string?

Tags: python, list, startswith

I'm trying to check is any item of a list starts with a certain string. How could I do this with a for loop? IE:

```
anyStartsWith = False
for item in myList:
    if item.startsWith('qwerty'):
        anyStartsWith = True
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
any(item.startswith('qwerty') for item in myList)
```

Comment: Argh beat me to it! But yes this is the best way I think.

Comment: Thanks, that just about completes the validation of my last 72 hour of work!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with a for loop

```
anyStartsWith = False
for item in myList:
    if item[0:5]=='qwerty':
        anyStartsWith = True
```

the 0:5 takes the first 6 characters in the string you can adjust it as needed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for list items that starts with string 'aa'

```
your_list=['aab','aba','abc','Aac','caa']
check_start='aa'
res=[value for value in your_list if value[0:2].lower() == check_start.lower()]
print (res)
```